# Gherkin Scenarios for User Input Validation

Tags: bdd

When writing a BDD scenario that is validating information on an input form, how would you list rules.

Options are:

1) A single scenario each rule
2) Scenario outline with examples for each field and rule

How do we say something is invalid that is not in a certain character set, e.g:

Given I enter a value that breaks the rule..
When I do something
Then I should see an error .....

Would you generate random values that break the rule?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 4):

With validation, I've done one of these:

- validated each kind of thing that might go wrong, or
- captured the validation behaviour with unit tests, then just described how I, the user, will see the validation message
- captured the common things that users do wrong and described how the system will help me to get it right.

I find the second and third ones easier to maintain, especially using a BDD tool, given that English is hard to refactor and validation rules often change. If there's no higher-level business capability which is provided, as in the third situation, then I'd just do the second one.

BDD isn't really about testing. It's about coming to a shared understanding and capturing that in a way which helps that understanding play into the code. You get tests as a wonderful by-product.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your description @Lunivore. I am looking for a good example of that but I haven't found it yet. If you have a link, can you please share? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Bomboca, afraid all my examples are with clients, and I have no access. You could try asking the BDD group: https://groups.google.com/d/forum/behaviordrivendevelopment‎